# access four elements from array at the same time vhdl

Tags: vhdl

how can i access four elements from a 2d array or array of array in one process at the same time? 
in this sample, i am trying to access intg1 at the same time, the synthesis is taking for ever.

```
type img_whole is array (78 downto 0, 130 downto 0) of std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal img1: img_whole;

signal i1_1: integer range 0 to 79:=0;
signal j1_1:integer range 0 to 131:=0;

type intg is array (78 downto 0, 130 downto 0) of integer range 0 to 1751998;--no double??
signal intg1 : intg;



integral :process (clka,finished,finished1)
variable tempo: integer range 0 to 1751998;


begin

if clka'event and clka = '1' then
if finished="1" and finished1="0" then
if i1_1 < 78 and j1_1 <130 then 

j1_1<=j1_1+1;
elsif j1_1=130 and i1_1<78 then
j1_1<=0 ;
i1_1<=i1_1+1;
elsif j1_1<130 and i1_1=78 then
j1_1<=j1_1+1;
elsif j1_1=130 and i1_1=78 then
    finished1<="1";
end if; 
tempo:= to_integer(unsigned('0' & img1(i1_1,j1_1)));

if i1_1-1>=0 then
tempo:=intg1(i1_1-1,j1_1)+tempo;

end if;
if j1_1-1>=0 then
tempo:=intg1(i1_1,j1_1-1)+tempo;

end if; 
if i1_1-1>=0 and j1_1-1>=0 then
tempo:=tempo-intg1(i1_1-1,j1_1-1);

end if;

   intg1(i1_1,j1_1)<=tempo;
    end if;
end if;
end process;
```

i am trying to access intg1 at the same time, the synthesis is taking for ever.
this code is for getting an integral image, out of a 2d array.

Comment: Can you provide the surrounding code inclusive signal and variable declarations?

Comment: The extended synthesis time may be a result of complexity (depth) of the created logical, whereby the tool cant fit or close timing for the design.  Each `if` will add a mux level in the data path, and each access to `intg1` may require duplication of a (wide) RAM if `intg1` is in RAM.  So as Paebbels notes, please provide the entire design, to allow a more complete understanding of the problem.

Comment: i have added more details above. thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are both functional and synthesis issues in the code.

Functional issues:

- `finished1` is only driven to `'1'` in the process, but never to `'0'`, so if the initial value is `'0'` then the operation in the process can only be done once after power up, since the `finished1` value of `'1'` will then inhibit further updates due to the process enable condition.
- `i1_1` and `j1_1` are signals that are driven in the start of the process, and then used later in the process, but since signals, the value assigned with `<=` is not available until next process evaluation.  Is that intentional?

Use a simulator to ensure correct functionality, which can be done before synthesis.

Synthesis issues:

- `intg1` is a table with at least 79 * 131 > 10 K entries, each of log2(1751999) <= 18 bits, thus a pretty large table.  The design requires asynchronous lookup in the table, since there is no extra cycle (clock edge) available from a new value of index e.g. `i1_1` and until the output of the process is generated based on the table lookup.  An asynchronous lookup in a large table requires a huge mux network, which is probably the reason for the long synthesis time.  And this lookup is even done multiple times based on different index values.
- Minor: `finished`, and  `finished1` are not needed in the sensitivity list of the process, since this is a process clocked by the `clka`.

The above list of issues may not be complete.

To fix the table lookup problem (first synthesis issue), make a pipe-lined design with cycles e.g.:

1. Index values `i1_1` etc. are generated
2. `intg1` table lookup synchronously
3. Intermediate `tempo` is generated, and `intg1` is updated.

The current design does step 2. and 3. in a single cycle, whereby it is not possible to make a synchronous lookup in the table, since there is only one clock edge in the cycle, and this is used for writing back to the `intg1` table.  So by splitting the lookup and write back operation in two cycles, it is possible both to have a clock edge for reading the table (synchronous read) and for writing the table.  Such a synchronous read using a clock edge is much more efficient based on the available hardware resources in typical FPGAs, since these contains large synchronous RAMs similar to the `intg1` table, thus the implementation will be smaller and faster.  The synchronous `intg1` lookup is made by simply adding a clocked process where signals are driven directly by the `intg1` output based in the required index values.  All the required reads must be made, then the subsequent process can then determine which of the read value that are actually used.

The specific pipeline implementation must be adapted to the design requirements.

Comment: i1_1 and j1_1 are intentionally incremented at the end of the process. and the whole process must be repeated until finished1 becomes 1 , then it will not be repeated any more. the ise gave me a warning that i should put finished1 and finished in the sensitivity list, because they are in the if clause. i checked the whole design in the simulator it gave correct results. but the problem is with the synthesis. and im not undertanding well what you mean by using the pipeline, can you explain it further?

Comment: Updated answer with lengthy description after the numbered bullets.

Comment: so what u are suggesting is to use a block ram where the read and write are synchronous signals

Comment: The important part is that the read is synchronous, thus make at clock edge and returned a cycle later, since that is the RAM type typically available for large tables in the in device.  By tailoring the design to the available hardware resources, the synthesis tool can make a much smaller and faster design, and will complete in much less time.

Comment: If you have block ram (10k+ bits per RAM block) available that allows asynchronous reads, that would probably work fine. I have never seen an FPGA that has block RAM with asynchronous reads though, and large LUTRAMs are always a bad idea.